# sql server reporting services suddenly stop responding and then come back again

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I had the strangest experience with SSRS today. Out of sudden, it stopped to respond. You couldn't access the web interface from browser. You couldn't access the web service to generate a report.

Error log showed nothing, Reporting Services Configuration Manager showed nothing. Everything seemed to be ok, except that SSRS weren't really working.

Service restart didn't help. Server reboot didn't help. I started to search internet for possible solutions and then after two or three hours, out of the blue, it came back again. I didn't change anything on the server, because I didn't have slightest idea what to do, still it came back to life.

Has anyone seen such magic too? What would you do if this happened to you?

I checked C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles for error files and they weren't helpful at all. Is there any better way to debug SSRS?

Comment: When you say 'Error Log', do you mean you combed through the Windows Event Viewer logs as well? Given the scenario you just painted, the Windows logs would be one of the first places I'd go to see if there were forces external to SQL Server causing problems.

Comment: @DCaugs yes, I looked into event viewer, but no errors or warnings there. There is lot of items with Information status, but here I don't really know what to look for.